# How to sort and filter datasourcebindings in Extension task.json while populating a picklist

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-devops-extensions, json-path-expression

I am using an API to get the available AKS Versions in a pick list in my Utility. I want to show only latest 4 versions in high to low order.

The current version of my code gives all of the available versions in that region-

```
{
   "name": "kubeVersion",
  "type": "picklist",
  "label": "Kubernetes Version",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "required": true,
  "helpMarkDown": "Select the version of the Kubernetes that needs to be installed on the AKS cluster.",
 
},
.
.
.
 {
   "target": "kubeVersion",
   "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
   "endpointUrl": "{{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/locations/$(rsgLocation)/orchestrators?api-version=2019-04-01&resource-type=managedClusters",
   "resultSelector": 
   "jsonpath:$.properties.orchestrators[*].orchestratorVersion",
   "parameters": {
    "rsgLocation": "$(rsgLocation)"
  }
},
```

In above code I am giving [*] in jsonpath that selects all of the available values. Which goes like
1.10.12

1.10.13

.

.

.

1.14.6

1.15.3

Could you please help me add filters and sorting there? I want to be sort these values from latest to earliest and take only top 4 versions. Later the requirement might change to 1.X.* and 1.Y.* so I want to be able to filter as well. Could you please tell me what kind of notations these are and where I can learn it from? I'd really appreciate any suggestion to fulfill these requirements.

Comment: Which API do you use?

Comment: @CharlesXu   Its there in the EndPoint URL :
"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/locations/{rsgLocation}/orchestrators?api-version=2019-04-01&resource-type=managedClusters"